# arm-linux-gnueabi-ld and fpc ppcrossarm still links to linux-i386

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, freepascal

I was able to build a freepascal crosscompiler for arm, but now when i want to build a a simple graphical app in lazarus or rebuild LCL the compilation works until is called arm-linux-gnueabi-ld which one still looking for all graphics librarys in /usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/4.9/ instead /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.9. so how i can fix it?

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o when searching for /usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o
```

Comment: How are you invoking the linker? In particular, what include and library search paths are you giving it?

Comment: (if you compile with -s there will be a ppas.sh with generated the assembler and linker cmdlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the relevant -FD or -Fl lines in your fpc.cfg under #ifdef i386

So e.g.

```
#ifdef cpui386
 -Fl/lib
 -Fl/usr/lib
 -Fl/usr/lib/i586-linux-gnu/4.9
#endif
```

and add an appropriate entry for ARM

See [here](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progap7.html) for a list of architecture specific defines. [The Buildfaq](http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf) has some more detailed information.